# jQuery autofill form can't work

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

[i want autofill in "Nama Pegawai" if i select "Id Pegawai"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eZIS.png)

please somebody who understand what a code to make autofill help me. i've tried but it not work.

this is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Id Pegawai</label>
<select name="id_pegawai" id="id_pegawai" onkeyup="autofill()" class ="form-
control">
<option value="#" disabled selected >Pilih ID Pegawai</option>
<?php 
 @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 mysql_select_db("gorden_interior");
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pegawai");
 if(mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0){
    while($pegawai = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        echo '<option>'.$pegawai['id_pegawai'].'</option>';
    }
}
?>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Nama Pegawai</label>
<input type="text" name="nama_pegawai" id="nama_pegawai" readonly 
class="form-control">
</div>

</table>
</form>
<script href="<?php echo base_url('assets/javascript/jquery-3.1.1.min.js');?
>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function autofill(){
        var id_pegawai = $("#id_pegawai").val();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'proses.php',
            data : 'id_pegawai='+id_pegawai,
        }).success(function(data){
            var json = data,
            obj = JSON.parse(json);
            $("#nama_pegawai").val(obj.nama_pegawai);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Thank You

Comment: please show use the code you have already

Comment: that's my code sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your select `onkeyup="autofill()"` has to be changed to `onchange="autofill()"`.

`onkeyup` only fires when there is a keypress.

Comment: already changed but still not work sir , its the function autofill() correct?

Comment: @MuhammadAliefAgusta we need so see what the ajax calls returns. It's hard to tell now. The code should be working.

Comment: but the keyup is on a select - I think you are confused as to what autofill is. Normally a keyup event would be on a text box and as you type it completes based on data returned through the AJAX call. What you seem to be trying to do is autopopulate a text input based on the value of a select, right?

Comment: To clarify the AJAX call will take place on change as its an on change event that is fired when you change the values of the Select. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#idOfSelect").on("change",function(){
$thisVal = $("#idOfSelect option:selected").text();
$("#idOfTextInput").val($thisVal);
})
```

Haven't tested but it should be something like the above. If it's the value of the select you want change

```
$("#idOfSelect option:selected").text()
```

to

```
$("#idOfSelect").val()
```

Comment: line 3: You don't use onkeyup with a select, you would use onchange

Comment: There's a lot I just couldn't debug that code. Do you understand it yourself? Why are you using php to echo the script href for jquery? What errors do you see in the console? Is the file proses.php loading OK? What is the json that get's returned? Any errors in it?